# display text when the timer reaches a specific time

Tags: android, timer, settext, chronometer

i´m making an app that shows random sentences when you press a botton, this process is pefect, part of my code is:

```
 botonok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Resources res = getResources();
            myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 
            String a = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            TextView elemento1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elemento1);
            elemento1.setText(a);
```

...

the problem, i need these sentence appear gradually, for example, the 1st sentence "elemento1" should appears just when you click the botton, the 2nd sentence, half second later, the 3rd sentece, one second later.. i have 4 sentences, as you can see, they are from an array.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a Timer after the class.

static volatile int time;
Timer t = new Timer();

now edit your function like this

```
  botonok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Resources res = getResources();
        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 
        String a = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        time=1;

        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


                public void run() {
        TextView elemento1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elemento1);
        if(time==0||time==2||time==4||time==6)
        elemento1.setText(a);
        time=time+1;
        }
                }

            });

        }
    }, 100, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you, I wrote your code and it work!! i had to make some changes, please read my answer..

Answer (score 0):

thank you, i just wrote your code and it work!! i had to make some changes, coz there are more textView, and my code is this:

```
botonok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
time=1; 
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if(time==2){
                      Resources res = getResources();
         myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);    
         String a = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];          
     TextView elemento1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elemento1);
            elemento1.setText(a);
                            }
                            //
                        if(time==4){
                      Resources res = getResources();
          myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray2); 
         String b = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
     TextView elemento2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elemento2);
            elemento2.setText(b);
```

// here i write the same process for (elemento3 and elemento4)
// then i write the last line:

```
}time=time+1; 
                        }
                    });
        }
}, 100, 1000)   ;
            ;}
});}}
```

but, there is a little mistake, the first time i touch the botton, the time is 2,4,6,8 but avery time i touch it, it gets faster, i wrote a conditional "countTouch++" but it didn´t work :(

Comment: Thanks for appreciation ! if you can elaborate what exactly you mean by faster then i might help u

Comment: well, this code is fine, but every time I touch the button, the times get shorter, the first time is (2,4,6,8), the sencod time is (1/2, 1, 1 1/2, 2) so on until I get them about the same time... I don´t know why..